# How to expose the Mac OS X Yosemite Markup action extension for images in a custom NSView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I have a basic Cocoa app that lets users edit text documents containing images using an embedded WebView (via `<div contenteditable="true">...</div>`).

This is very similar to composing a message in Mail (the editor used there is also a WebView).

Similar to Mail, I would like to expose the Markup action extension inside my app to let users add markup to images right within my app.

After watching the "Creating Extensions" videos from WWDC 2014, I'm still not sure if it is possible to expose action extensions from a custom view (something like the sharing service picker).

In the second part of the WWDC videos, they mention that `NSTextView` has built-in support for action extensions, but what if I need to expose action extensions through a custom view?

Here's an example of what this looks like in Mail:

[image: Example of the markup extension]

Comment: I filed an enhancement request. Have not heard back yet.

Comment: I've just answered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29580096/446039), which is quite similar to what you're asking. Basically, there is no good way to do what you're asking but there is a hacky workaround that can be used.

Comment: @Josh Thanks for the heads-up. I thought about that workaround, but it will be too difficult in my case (embedded WebView). I filed a bug with Apple as enhancement request. I hope that they open up the API at some point.

Comment: ah yeah, no worries at all mate – I've also filed a bug and hope they open it up soon!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Image Editing extensions on Yosemite in own app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287516/using-image-editing-extensions-on-yosemite-in-own-app)