# Using Image Editing extensions on Yosemite in own app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-yosemite

In my OS X app, I want to let the user edit images with the appropriate action extensions installed on his/her Mac, e.g the image markup extension as present in Mail.app or TextEdit (for RTFD files with images) - or Pixelmator's repair tool if available. As far as I can recall, Apple announces at WWDC '14 there would be a public API for this task.

Unfortunately I cannot find any starting point on how to use extensions from a host app perspective, neither documentation- nor sample-code-wise.

I found out that you have to set the undocumented style property of the NSSharingPicker to a non-zero value like this:

```
- (IBAction)testSharingPicker:(id)sender
{
    NSSharingServicePicker *picker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:@[[self.listing.images.firstObject thumbImage]]];

    [picker setValue:@(1) forKey:@"style"];
    [picker setDelegate:self];

    [picker showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
}
```

Once the style value is set, you know you are on the right track, because `- (NSArray *)sharingServicePicker:(NSSharingServicePicker *)sharingServicePicker sharingServicesForItems:(NSArray *)items proposedSharingServices:(NSArray *)proposedServices`is called with the image editing extensions installed on my system, instead of the regular sharing extensions.

You also need to implement an undocumented delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)sharingServicePicker:(NSSharingServicePicker *)sharingService shouldShowForView:(NSView*) inView
{
    return YES;
}
```

But still, the picker is not showing up. All I get is some weird border around the `sender`button.

Comment: Did you play with `-sharingService:sourceFrameOnScreenForShareItem:` `- sharingService:transitionImageForShareItem:contentRect:` and `-sharingService:sourceWindowForShareItems:sharingContentScope:` ?

Comment: Yes, I implemented all these methods. Doesn't make any difference. I don't get to the point where they are called.

Comment: eMail <dts@apple.com> or file an enhancement request (bug report @:<http://bugreporter.apple.com>) and request an official answer.

Comment: Note that the result of the OP's discoveries are available on GitHub and worth a look! https://github.com/iljaiwas/NSSharingPickerTest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems Apple only really exposes Action Extensions through `NSTextView` at the present time.

> [On OS X, NSTextView plays the central role in presenting Extensions to the users.](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/217)

That is achievable by creating a `NSTextView` and inserting an image into it as a `NSFileWrapper`, for example (this code adapted from [TextEdit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html)):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attachments = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
NSError *error;
    NSFileWrapper *wrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/user/Downloads/Test.png"] options:NSFileWrapperReadingImmediate error:&error];
    if (wrapper) {
        NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithFileWrapper:wrapper];
        [attachments appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment]];
}

if ([attachments length] > 0) {
    NSRange selectionRange = [self.textView selectedRange];
    if ([self.textView shouldChangeTextInRange:selectionRange replacementString:[attachments string]]) {
        [[self.textView textStorage] replaceCharactersInRange:selectionRange withAttributedString:attachments];
        [self.textView didChangeText];
    }
}
```

[image: NSTextView displaying Extensions]

(Note that inserting an image as a `NSTextAttachmentCell` causes a weird crash – [rdar://20333977](http://openradar.appspot.com/20333977))

That weird border you mention seems to be the Sharing Service Picker that's shown when hovering over an image in a `NSTextView`, however obscured slightly by the button.

[image: NSButton displaying private NSSharingServicePicker menu]

I stumbled on [your GitHub repo](https://github.com/iljaiwas/NSSharingPickerTest) and have contributed what I've learnt about it in [this pull request](https://github.com/iljaiwas/NSSharingPickerTest/pull/1).

I've achieved a hacky workaround by presenting the `NSSharingServicePicker` as described in your question and then holding onto the `NSSharingService`s returned in `sharingServicePicker:sharingServicesForItems:proposedSharingServices:`. The services themselves can then be invoked with `performWithItems:` and data is returned in `sharingService:didShareItems:`.

My code is available [here](https://github.com/josh-/NSSharingPickerTest).

Comment: +1 The resulting GitHub repo is pure gold for reference material: https://github.com/iljaiwas/NSSharingPickerTest

Answer (score 0):

Actually,hacking "style" property and implementing NSSharingServicePickerDelegate are unnecessary,the following code is more eligible(of course,you should implement NSSharingServiceDelegate protocol):

```
- (IBAction)onServiceBtnClick:(id)sender {
NSURL *url = [self.quickLookItems firstObject];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
if (image) {
    self.serviceBtn.hidden = YES;

    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sharing"];

    NSSharingService *service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:@"com.apple.Preview.Markup"];
    service.delegate = self;
    self.markupService = service;
    NSArray *services = @[ service ];

    for (NSSharingService *service in services) {
        NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:service.title action:@selector(share:) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [menu addItem:menuItem];
    }

    [menu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:[NSEvent mouseLocation] inView:nil];


    }
}

- (void)share:(NSMenuItem *)sender{
     NSURL *imageURL = [self.quickLookItems firstObject];
     [self.markupService performWithItems:@[imageURL]];
 }
```

Comment: not working on macOS High Sierra and `com.apple.Preview.Markup` seems to be private.