# How do we integrate system photo editing into our macOS apps?

Tags: macos, cocoa, photos

Multiple third-party macOS apps now have a feature to edit photos, and the UI looks exactly the same as in Preview. How do we implement this functionality? Has a new framework been released?

Including links to screenshots for comparison. Some buttons are not included in the third-party app, but the UI and the behaviour is exactly the same in both apps.

**Shotty (3rd party app) image editing controls**

[image]

**Apple Preview image editing controls**
  [image]

Your help would be greatly appreciated, a link to Apple documentation would already be helpful.

Comment: Looks like what you see is an [action extension](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/action-extensions/) for images. If you add an `NSTextView` to your app with `importsGraphics` and `allowsImageEditing` set to `true`, you have a host app that supports those extensions. Just like TextEdit or Mail. But I am not sure how to support the extensions without an `NSTextView`. An `NSImageView` or `IKImageView` seems not to support it out of the box, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The above workaround also works with `NSTextField`.

Comment: Looks like your question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287516/using-image-editing-extensions-on-yosemite-in-own-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Image Editing extensions on Yosemite in own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287516/using-image-editing-extensions-on-yosemite-in-own-app)